# jquery ajax failed with large data

Tags: ajax, debugging, jquery

Passing huge ammount of data from jquery ajax is failed,is there any way to reolve this issue.I given type as POST.Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Raju

Comment: Please try to be more specific.  What exactly are you trying to do, and what exactly is the data you're trying to process?  The obvious answer would be "Don't pass so much data" :)

Comment: And what does 'failed' mean? Network time out?

Comment: Please add more detail and show some code.

Comment: Also, how do you know it failed? You get an error message?

Comment: Why the down vote? The question may very well be vague but there is more than enough to give him some direction.

Comment: huge ? be discrete. How huge ? any measurement ? Whats is the Problem ? Timeout ? I hope you are Sync'ing your innerHTML with the response. Have you tried to get the response directly through the Browser ? without any AJAX Call ?

Comment: yes i tried with out ajax it working for me,I am getting error as undefined and status as object error.

Comment: @Derek - no there is not! he didn't specify the data types he's sending, server side, error message...

Answer (score 3):

*This is how i step through an ajax request to debug it and it works most of the time.*

*(**edit**: i've changed this answer slightly because i assumed OP was using PHP)*

### First

Check to see if the browser is throwing you any errors.  You can do so by checking out [**FireBug**](http://getfirebug.com/) (firefox extension) OR in the webkit dev tools (I prefer [**chrome dev tools**](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/)).  This is the first and most obvious error you can make *(syntax)*.

### Next

Given your description it's evident your script is timing out, but just to be safe utilize the $.ajax() success callback to see what your response is.  Make sure you are posting the expected data appropriately.

### Check for Server Side errors

Make sure everything is good to go in the script you are executing via ajax.

### Finally...

It's likely your request is timing out due to the large amount of data and the time it takes to process/send it back.  Try specifying the timeout in jQuery.

You can do so via the [**$.ajaxSetup()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) api if you'd like it to apply to all of your ajax requests.

### OR

Where you are making the *actual* request.

EX:

```
$.ajax({
  //set a timeout for 10 seconds
  timeout: 10000
});
```

Comment: There are indeed some PHP settings which can be checked. max_execution_time, upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, memory_limit. However I don't know what exactly goes wrong with the Ajax call, so I'm just guessing here.

Comment: right, well those are all good suspects if the other things i've outlined don't help.  The original poster is simply confused because his request is breaking with a large ajax call.

Comment: I checked syntax in code,my request only fails if i send huge data.I mentioned type as POST.

Comment: did you read the rest of my answer? timeout?

Comment: How can i define huge,sending all the data with query string but i defined type as post.

Comment: Yes i added timeout also ,but no luck.. $.ajax({ 
type:"POST", 
url:testUrl,timeout:10000,
dataType: 
"json",

Comment: Even I found that request not going to server...,

Comment: do you even know what the error is yet?  In order to get some help you might want to supply more than your vague problem.

Comment: The file you're sending to the server is massive then? I was under the impression your response was large. <del>it could be something in php.ini</del> although I just realized you never specified the server-side language.  What server-side language are you using?

Comment: No i dont know what error it is,MAy be this is the problem with query string i passed.Same function works with if i send 10 30 records,if i reach morethan that ajax request fail.i am sure it is not syntax issue.

Comment: I am using jsp and java.

Answer (score 3):

After reading jquery userguide,i understood that it wont allow query string if url length is more than 2020,IIS server simply discard it as per Microsoft.

I send data as key value pairs instaed of passing data as query string.

I dont understand what are down votes,i clearly mentioned in my query type as post,large data passing as query string.

Thanks once again to all of you giving answers.